# Tag *random* very non-specific

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization

The tag [random](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) (without wiki) seems to be used for a lot of different things, like random factors, random variables, ... Probably a lot should be retagged, and the rest changed (by a synonym) to tag [randomness](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomness). Opinions?

See the earlier [Ambiguous [randomization] tag and friends](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/ambiguous-randomization-tag-and-friends)

Comment: "Random" probably should be relegated to the set of tags that are so non-specific as to be worthless, such as "statistics."

Comment: At a quick glance many could have the tag deleted without loss of information and others re-tagged. I will have a go when it is clear we have a consensus. I assume then the mods can ban the tag in some magical way.

Comment: Looks like a consensus for me now!

Comment: [Burninate and blacklist it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag)

Comment: OK, I have started. I plan to do between 5 and 10 a day but no more than 5 at a time.

Comment: @mdewey: That's fine, I do a few also. I will look into what  proposes ...

Comment: "seems to be used for a lot of different things" Wow. Almost like people ascribe meaning to it at ran— ;)

Comment: @Alexis: That is a very precise observation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, there are no more [random](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) posts left.  For the future, we need to see into blacklisting ... as mentioned in a comment by @Stephan Kolassa.

Comment: Better get in quick as they seem to come in frequently.

Comment: There is a (modes-only?) list of new tags that I frequent, and nuke a lot! I will ask another question about a list for blacklisting ...